# Endless builds with eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Workspace Settings

[image]

Build Options

[image]

Does anyone know why eclipse never ends building when I check "Refresh using native hooks or polling"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just found out that the build creates a jar file in the eclipse project, which triggers a build again and so on...

In case someone faces the same problem in the future:

To solve the problem right click on the folder, go to properties and add a resource filter so eclipse doesn't care about this particular file anymore.